# Torque free rigid body

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, rigid-body-dynamics

Is kinetic energy constant for a rigid body with one fixed point and no torque, if so how to prove it? I'm considering free rotation.

Comment: Do you mean it is rotating with constant angular velocity (no net torque) around a fixed point?

Comment: i don't think that angular velocity is constant if net torque is zero.

Comment: http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/ns541_fall2010_notes04/Newton1_rot.html It's like Newton's first law, but for rotations. velocity $\rightarrow$ angular velocity, and force $\rightarrow$ torque

Comment: i am considering torque free precession, i am trying to understand poinsots construction. there is no fixed axis. i am referring to free rotation.

Comment: If the energy is conserved thus $\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{dT}{dt}=0$ thus T=const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the kinetic energy of the body, and measure it at the pivot where there is zero velocity

$$ K=\tfrac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\mathbf{I}_{A}\boldsymbol{\omega} $$

where $\mathbf{I}_A$ is the mass moment of inertia tensor at the pivot.

Now consider the component of MMOI along the rotation axis as

$$ I_A = \boldsymbol{z}\cdot\mathbf{I}_{A}\boldsymbol{z} $$

where $\boldsymbol{z}$ is the direction of rotation. The speed of rotation is $\dot{\theta}$ and thus:

$$\boldsymbol{\omega}=\boldsymbol{z}\,\dot{\theta}$$

As such the kinetic energy is

$$ K = \tfrac{1}{2} I_A \dot{\theta}^2 $$

Now if there is no torques and no forces that do work on the body (only the pivot reaction forces & moments) then the acceleration is zero $\ddot{\theta}=0$ and the speed is constant $\dot{\theta} = \text{(const)}$.

Finally, the component of the MMOI along the rotation axis is also constant since the rotation axis is fixed on the body.

So in the end, the kinetic energy is constant also.

Answer (score 1):

There is no change in kinetic energy (translational and rotational) of a rigid body if there is no net force and no net torque on the body.

> i am considering torque free precession

I'm not familiar with torque free precession, but according to Wikipedia while angular momentum is a constant the angular velocity vector changes orientation with time. That, however, does not mean that the *magnitude* of the angular velocity, or rotational speed, changes. If there are no external net forces or net torques acting on the object, then there can be no net work done on the object. Per the work energy theorem the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

Since no net work is done on the object undergoing torque free precession, the kinetic energy must remain constant.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Free rotation with one point fixed, not constrained to an axis

Comment: @user199996 maybe you should draw a picture

Comment: @user199996 Your comment on this answer contradicts your comment on the question: " there is no fixed axis. i am referring to free rotation." If one point is fixed and there is zero torque about any point, the axis of rotation is fixed.

Comment: @BillN Zero torque about that fixed point. There is precession happening. Angular velocity won't be constant. Use Euler's equations. We can visualise using poinsots construction.

Comment: @user199996 Why didn't you just say in your post you were talking about torque free precession? It wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @user199996 If there is zero torque about a point, the angular velocity about that point cannot change. It MUST be constant. If there is zero torque about all points, the angular velocity about all point MUST be constant. Angular velocity CANNOT change without a torque, your assertions notwithstanding. You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: @BillN I'm not familiar with torque free precession, but according to Wikipedia while angular momentum is a constant the angular velocity vector changes orientation with time. Not sure if a change in the orientation of the angular velocity vector is the same thing as saying angular velocity changes.

Comment: @BillN But I still believe if there are no net forces or torques on the rigid body, there can be no net change in kinetic energy over time, based on the work energy theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy for rotation is $$K = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$

Since there is no torque, $\omega$ is constant (by Newton's first law for rotations). And if there is no change in the mass distribution, *I* is constant. This means the kinetic energy, *K*, is constant.

If the object is also moving through space (not just spinning), you would have another kinetic energy term $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. If there is a net *force* then *v* would not be constant. This would make $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ not constant, meaning the total kinetic energy $$K_{total} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$ is not constant.

If there is no net force and no net torque, then $K_{total}$ is constant.

Comment: I am considering Free rotation with one point fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to ask ourselves how could the kinetic energy of an object change (considering only mechanical systems)? The answer is that if a force or a torque acts on it, then the kinetic energy will change.

Now if an object is rotating in free space about its centre of mass, it’s kinetic energy can change if there is a change in the velocity of the centre of mass. That is, the point about which it is rotating is accelerating due to some external force that is acting at the centre of mass. In this case it’s rotational velocity is fixed but not translational.

However if we are fixing one of the ends by means of some constraint, then there is no way to apply force on the rotating object such that the torque is zero. Thus in that case the total kinetic energy will be constant for a pivoted object rotating at fixed velocity.